# All designer files stopped updating in (VS 2015 .NET 4.6.1)

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, webforms, visual-studio-2015

I am running Visual Studio 2015 (Update 1, .NET Framework 4.6.1) and all designer files stopped auto-updating in my project. In the past I used to have this happen with one file and I would simply recreate the designer for that one file, but I never had it happen on the project file like this.

Some solutions say to go to C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319 and then your projects folder and clear all temp files, but none of my project's folders are in here.

Microsoft Visual Studio Enterprise 2015
Version 13.0.24720.00 Update 1
All of the latest .NET Frameworks installed (4.5, 4.6, 4.6.1)
Everything is fully up to date

Answer (score 1):

The only fix that I found was to take a backup of my project and re-create it as a new project.

In my case I just took a backup of my local non-working project got latest from source control which created a new project.

It definitely has to do with visual studio files being out of sync which causes locking of the designer files.